# 'OR' Filtering on Columns in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I've got an oddly set up google sheet as my data source for a powerBI dashboard. Right now my main stress point is a 'last 7 days' filter that needs to be applied. The problem is that there are multiple columns containing dates that could be in the last 7 days, in this case representing multiple steps in an email chain.

If any one of those columns contains a date in the last 7 days, then I need to capture the row in most of my visualizations and tables, but if I just use standard filters, PowerBI assumes 'AND' and displays none of the rows, since there will almost never be a row where multiple date entries are in the last 7 days.

I'm almost certain there is a way to do this with either merged columns or calculated fields, or maybe there is even something as simple as an 'OR' filter, but thus far my googling has not turned up anything. Do you know a work around for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In Power Query Editor, create a duplicate column for each of your date fields.

Make sure each of the duplicated columns is in Date format and then calculate the "Age". You will get a time value. In the Transform pane, use the "Duration" function and convert to "Days". Do this for each of the duplicated columns.

Now the last step: Create a "conditional column" in the "Add column" pane, and pull all of these new columns that should now have integer values and set the condition to show "Yes" if less than or equal to 7, "No" if more than 7.

Let me know if this helps.